# Unable to call Struts2 Action using Jquery Ajax in Liferay

Tags: jquery, struts2, liferay

I was Unable to call Struts2 Action using Jquery Ajax in Liferay6.1

Please see the following files , i pasted below and let me know if this is not the way to call

**Jsp page**

```
<portlet:renderURL var="getChartData" windowState="<%= LiferayWindowState.EXCLUSIVE.toString() %>">
<portlet:param name="struts_action" value="/getChartData" />
</portlet:renderURL>



 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
     alert('jjjj');
     $.ajax({
         type : 'POST',
         url  : '<%=getChartData%>',
         data: "countryId="+countryId,
         success : function(data){
             alert(data);
         }
     });

});
</script>
```

**struts.xml**

```
<action name="getChartData" class="com.actions.ImageDisplayAction" method="getChartData">
            <result name="success">/WEB-INF/view/blank.jsp</result>
        </action>
```

**portlet.xml**

```
<portlet>
        <portlet-name>DisplayImages</portlet-name>
        <display-name>DisplayImages</display-name>

        <portlet-class>org.apache.struts2.portlet.dispatcher.Jsr168Dispatcher</portlet-class>
```

Action class

```
public class ImageDisplayAction extends ActionSupport {

    public String getChartData() {

        System.out.println("Hi ");
        System.out.println("Hi ");
        System.out.println("Hi ");
        System.out.println("Hi ");

        return SUCCESS;
    }

}
```

Updated part :

I am not getting any Exception , here is my complete struts.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
  <constant name="struts.multipart.saveDir" value="D:\\ant" />

    <package name="view" extends="struts-portlet-default">

        <action name="index" >
            <result name="input">/WEB-INF/view/index.jsp</result>           
            <result name="success">/WEB-INF/view/index.jsp</result>
        </action>       


         <action name="getChartData" class="com.actions.ImageDisplayAction" method="getChartData">
            <result name="success">/WEB-INF/view/blank.jsp</result>
        </action>


    </package>
</struts>
```

**This is inside my JSP file (No chnages )**

```
<portlet:renderURL var="getChartData" windowState="<%= LiferayWindowState.EXCLUSIVE.toString() %>">
<portlet:param name="struts_action" value="/getChartData" />
</portlet:renderURL>



 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
     alert('jjjj');
     $.ajax({
         type : 'POST',
         url  : '<%=getChartData%>',
         data: "countryId="+countryId,
         success : function(data){
             alert(data);
         }
     });

});
</script>
```

Comment: any error/exception you getting?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
<portlet:param name="struts_action" value="/getChartData" />
```

to

```
<portlet:param name="struts.portlet.action" value="/namespace/getChartData" />
```

Struts2 expects a param with that name.

On the other hand, struts may be trying to find the namespace for the action. The namespace should be defined in the attributes of the `<modules>` tag in struts.xml. (If this fails, try removing the namespace).

Comment: I am not using any namespace in struts.xml

Comment: If you're using Struts 2, *struts_action* should be changed to *struts.portlet.action*. Have you tried calling the URL using this? [Extra reference](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/3942878)